# Trouble updating G++ to version >5 using apt-get in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt-get, cmake, g++

Context: I'm trying to run CMake as described [here (under Linux-installing dependencies > Building OpenVDB)](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb/blob/master/README.md). I'm in WSL.

When I do so I get this error:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:259 (message):
  Support for CMake versions < 3.12 is deprecated and will be removed.


-- CMake Build Type: Release
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:445 (message):
  Insufficient g++ version.  Minimum required is "6.3.1".  Found version
  "5.4.0"


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So it obviously needs G++ version 6 instead of 5. If I run `g++ --version`, I do indeed have version 5.4.0.

However I've been troubleshooting and I haven't had much luck actually updating G++. I ran `apt-get install g++-6` and it seemed to install the package, but the g++ version hasn't changed and I can't locate where g++-6 actually is.

I also ran `dpkg -L g++-6` and it claimed that g++-6 isn't installed. I'm learning WSL/apt/g++ as I go here so I might be ignorant about obvious things I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The problem you are having probably has nothing to do with WSL.  If you check the problem you are having against whatever distro you are running (as if you had no WSL at all), you will probably find a solution.  Unfortunately, I *can only guess* that you are running Debian or Ubuntu.. because you didn't bother to tell anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wasn't sure what distribution I was running on (I was just running an application called 'wsl'). Senor CMasMas's comment inspired me to investigate, and installing Debian from the [Microsoft store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/debian/9msvkqc78pk6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) and repeating the steps I'd previously followed allowed me to install a more recent version of G++.